# Two rows layout with only css

Tags: html, css

I need to create a 2 rows layout for a web page to manage a section for filters and other section for results with the following characteristics:

- the page cannot overflow the height of 100%
- the height of the first row is based on his content (could be variable and a javascript function can change it by hiding some elements)
- the height of the second row is the difference between 100% and the height of first row
- **in the second row the div with overflow must be the one with class "list" and I can't move it to div with class="result" (that will make it work)**

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="filter">
        <div class="filtercontent">
            filter content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <div class="resultcontent">
            <div class="list">
                <div class="listcontent">
                    list content    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.filter {
    width: 100%;
}

.result {
    width: 100%;
}

.resultcontent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.list {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.listcontent {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 2000px;
}
```

I tried with flexbox (in different ways) but I can't find a solution for the last point.

IMPORTANT: I can't use javascript to set the height of the rows. I need a solution using only CSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your .result div with "flex: 1" property it will take all space remaining in the outer div (.main). So if the .filter div occupies 500 height pixels the .result will adjust in the blank space filling the 100% from the parent. If you change it dynamically hiding or adding elements flex: 1 will guarantee that all remaining space will be populated by .result automatically.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried to set "flex: 1", but his child (which has height: 100%) cannot detect the real height of his parent

Comment: That's because this form of properties declaration (with percentage) is always relative to its parent, always "cascading" up through the root element. If you set height: 100% to html and body elements and overflow: hidden to .main class you should be good to go.